# Can't Create more than one Button Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I duplicate my modal button and The problem is I can't show "Open Modal 2" in my code.

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
```

Here is my complete code:
https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/xn3npwc4/

What should I do? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different ID for your "Open Modal 2" elements.

According to definition and usage from W3School,

the getElementById() method accesses the first element with the specified id.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion you ignored what id means

Two button's ids are same which captions are Open Modal and Open Modal2

So btn variable is connected with only first element which id is myBtn

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps :)

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">×</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
</div>

</div>

<button id="myBtn2">Open Modal 2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">×</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
 </div>

  </div>


 <script>
 // Get the modal
 var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

 // Get the button that opens the modal
 var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
 var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

 // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
 btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
 }

  btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
 }

 // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
 }

 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have same id for yours button "Open Modal" and "Open Modal 2". When you write `var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");` then you got first of two of yours button. And any events you bind only for this *first* button. So you need to change id of second button for something like 'myBtn1' and use something like this piece of code to set event handlers:

```
function setModal(btn,modal) {
    btn.onclick=function() {
        modal.style.display="block";
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    var span=modal.querySelectorAll(".close") [0];
    span.onclick = function() {
         modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};

setModal(document.getElementById("myBtn"),document.getElementById('myModal'));
setModal(document.getElementById("myBtn1"),document.getElementById('myModal'));
```

I've modified your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1fgmfpfc/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML id conflict in Javascript ,it's a major issue of your code. `document.getElementById` always bind your upper HTML code like as when u change your modal2 code upper above than modal1 then modal2 open but not open in modal1, so define different HTML id or try to dynamic name of HTML id.